# Scraping issue not loading in matches not played

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, web-scraping

I am going to try and make this concise as possible. I am working on scraping some soccer data from fbref and I am having an issue getting the matches not yet played to load in to my data set for ML. An example of what I am looking to obtain is here under the "Scores and Fixtures" table.

https://fbref.com/en/squads/18bb7c10/Arsenal-Stats

when I run the code I am able to scrape all games played year to date, but not the upcoming matches I am trying to predict.

```
{import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

for year in years:
    data = requests.get(standings_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
    standings_table = soup.select('table.stats_table')[0]

    links = [l.get("href") for l in standings_table.find_all('a')]
    links = [l for l in links if '/squads/' in l]
    team_urls = [f"https://fbref.com{l}" for l in links]
    
    previous_season = soup.select("a.prev")[0].get("href")
    standings_url = f"https://fbref.com{previous_season}"
    
    for team_url in team_urls:
        team_name = team_url.split("/")[-1].replace("-Stats", "").replace("-", " ")
        data = requests.get(team_url)
        matches = pd.read_html(data.text, match="Scores & Fixtures")[0]
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
        links = [l.get("href") for l in soup.find_all('a')]
        links = [l for l in links if l and 'all_comps/shooting/' in l]
        data = requests.get(f"https://fbref.com{links[0]}")
        shooting = pd.read_html(data.text, match="Shooting")[0]
        shooting.columns = shooting.columns.droplevel()
        try:
            team_data = matches.merge(shooting[["Date", "Sh", "SoT", "Dist", "FK", "PK", "PKatt"]], on="Date")
        except ValueError:
            continue
        team_data = team_data[team_data["Comp"] == "Premier League"]
        
        team_data["Season"] = year
        team_data["Team"] = team_name
        all_matches.append(team_data)
        time.sleep(10)
```

I have tried adjusting the code to include more date ranges as well as tried to get rid of the header that separates them.

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason, I couldn't do it with beautifulsoup, but it did work with lxml and xpath - even using the same parser...

To get the "Scores and Fixtures" table, try this:

```
from lxml import html as lh
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://fbref.com/en/squads/18bb7c10/Arsenal-Stats"
req = requests.get(url)
doc = lh.fromstring(req.text)
table = doc.xpath('//div[@id="all_matchlogs"][.//caption[contains(.,"Fixtures")]]//table')[0]
df = pd.read_html(lh.tostring(table))[0]
df
```

The output should your expected table.